# The query result is unstable after the multi-copy file is damaged

Tags: cnosdb

version:
`cnosdb 2.3.0, revision f0cf70160e9eed8f49b00cc6e0c62b764796a78b`

cluster:
`3meta 2data`

1.Create a two-copy database after you connect the database:
`create database db1 with replica 2;`

2.Write a piece of data with the curl command:
`curl -XPOST -u "root:" "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=db1" -d "ma,ta=a fa=1"`

3.At this point, you will find that there are vnodes on both data nodes, and then drop the two vnodes through compact vnode :
`compact vnode <vnode-id>;`

4.Then modify and destroy the tsm file in one of the vnodes, and then query the table multiple times through sql, you will find that sometimes successful, sometimes failed:
`select * from ma;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a bug, which has already been fixed in the latest version of cnosdb.

```
cnosdb 2.3.1, revision 2e84f561b7661a3f90ed12a17f1616847c6c50bb
```